# Memory concerns pulling the same large dataset from a mono store across different components in React

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I'm using [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/) for state management in my React app but I think this might be a more general React question.

Zustand is a simple flux-like store where components subscribe to a store hook to retrieve values / methods from it. In my app, the store includes some very large datasets and I retrieve those store properties in several different components with something like:

`const dataset = useStore(state => state.largeDataset)`

My question is whether the `dataset` variable references or copies the value from the store? If it copies, then that means that each additional component that retrieves the value will take up an additional [size_of_dataset] amount of space?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the exact answer for you, but I did some digging on this:

Zustand uses `useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector` (or rather a shim) for this ([code](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/d27ea948843b2c955ce2be530e5e963dff8958de/src/react.ts#L6)), which is a new React API to subscribe to values of a "store". It adds things like observing, snapshotting etc. to react. You can read more about that function [here](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/86).

In any case, these functions all seem to be memoized and probably use Proxies under the hood, which should mean that the values are not loaded into the memory again and again. However, this is really just based on what I could find in the docs. I did try to find more in the [React RFC PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18000) without much success.

What I can tell you, is that I am also using zustand with very large datasets (Gigabites worth of Float32Arrays) and I don't have problems with selecting the data. I do have some with marking them as ready for the GC (which is how I found your question). So you should have an eye on that. I read that using a `WeakMap` for storing key/value pairs is a good idea?